Python not recognizing Ursina
Whenever I  try to import the module ursina in python, it says that the module is not found. 
When executing pip install ursina, it says Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable and then says that the requirements are already satisfied.
Code:
import ursina

Output:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ursina'

I can only run import ursina when using the python command in cmd, but it just kinda freezes and I have to stop it using Ctrl C.
Using Ctrl C gave me this traceback:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\oaoao\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python312\site-packages\ursina\__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    from ursina.camera import instance as camera
  File "C:\Users\oaoao\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python312\site-packages\ursina\camera.py", line 188, in <module>
    instance = Camera()
               ^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\oaoao\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python312\site-packages\ursina\ursinastuff.py", line 230, in __call__
    obj = type.__call__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\oaoao\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python312\site-packages\ursina\camera.py", line 36, in __init__
    self.overlay = Entity(parent=self.ui, model='quad', scale=99, color=color.clear, eternal=True, z=-99, add_to_scene_entities=False)
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\oaoao\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python312\site-packages\ursina\ursinastuff.py", line 230, in __call__
    obj = type.__call__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\oaoao\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python312\site-packages\ursina\entity.py", line 107, in __init__
    setattr(self, key, kwargs[key])
  File "C:\Users\oaoao\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python312\site-packages\ursina\entity.py", line 198, in model_setter
    m = load_model(value, application.asset_folder)
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\oaoao\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python312\site-packages\ursina\mesh_importer.py", line 52, in load_model
    for filename in path.glob(f'**/{name}{filetype}'):
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_3.12.1264.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\pathlib.py", line 1094, in glob
    for p in selector.select_from(self):
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_3.12.1264.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\pathlib.py", line 237, in _select_from
    for p in successor_select(starting_point, scandir):
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_3.12.1264.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\pathlib.py", line 204, in _select_from
    with scandir(parent_path) as scandir_it:
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_3.12.1264.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\pathlib.py", line 1063, in _scandir
    return os.scandir(self)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
KeyboardInterrupt

This could be caused by conflics as I had reinstalled ms-store python to fix the python command.

I solved the problem by deleting the conflicting ms-store python, the freeze part was just python being slow I think.

For the second part of your question, the traceback shows that ursina scans the application.asset_folder on initial import. The asset folder is determined from sys.argv[0]'s parent (i.e. normally the location of the script you run, but as you're running interactively, it's probably the current directory). It should run faster if you cd to a separate folder you create for your project and possibly if you run a .py  file saved in that folder instead of running interactively.
As for the first part, you seem to have figured it out given your comment in the staging ground ("I solved the problem by deleting the conflicting ms-store python, the freeze part was just python being slow I think".)
